# Algorithm for clustering by PCA line fit

Tags: python, graphics, scikit-learn

This is more of an applied maths / algorithm question than an a coding question, but as I'm trying to solve it in `sklearn` this seemed like a good place to ask.

I'm playing with writing a texture compressor for custom compression format. It stores a small number of color endpoints per block of texels and the does linear weighted combinations of those end points to recover a specific value per texel. The standard method for implementing this type of compressor is to use PCA to find the dominant axis, so your end-points are the data points at either end of that line, and then you interpolate along PCA axis to get the colors.

The format supports multiple partitions - each partition has its own color end points, and texels in the data block can be assigned to any single partition. One common trick to assign texels to partitions is to use kmeans clustering on the color values, but this tends to cluster "blobs" of pixels (the red circles in the figure below) which isn't really a good match for how the compression scheme wants to encode the data.

[image]
In this sample you can visually see there are really three "lines" of data points in the data (shown in black). These would be ideal selections for the algorithm - at least in terms of testing if they can encode with better quality - because a good fit to a line segment means a good fit linear interpolation between two endpoints.

Is there any standard algorithm for doing this kind of data point clustering around line fitting rather than spatial clustering?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting problem!  [and a field I've dabbled in](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/1551/209).

It strikes me that it might be related to ["Texture Compression with Adaptive Block Partitions" by Levkovich-Maslyuk, Kalyuzhny, and Zhirkov](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~cohen/Research/TexComp/Levkovich-Maslyuk2000-Texture%20Compression%20with%20Adaptive%20Block%20Patterns.pdf). In particular, have a look at figure 1.

Their system seems to work on independent small i.e. 8x8, blocks so the search space is kept reasonably contained. If you're planning on doing the same then perhaps their algorithm might still be applicable.

If not, e.g. your "linear sets" can be used, say, anywhere in the entire texture, then I doubt their approach would be feasible.

**[*Disclaimer: I've not tried the following myself*]**

Perhaps you  might still be able to use a VQ-like approach but, instead of using single colour as a representative for each subgroup (which, as you said, would lead to "blobs") could you not store 2 colours, i.e. defining a line segment?  I.e. rather than have "k-means" have "k-segments"?

Obviously your "best fit" is then a distance from the line segment and the "averaging" step of all nearest colours is then the PCA algorithm.

What you do when you want to generate new candidates is not so clear. Perhaps if you want N, you could simply start with a random set of N candidates and just repeatedly apply the best-fit and remapping algorithm.

Alternatively, perhaps finding the worst-matching pixel(s) each iteration could be used to generate a new candidate.

One of these seems to me to be worth investigating.

What I was curious about is how many bits you were planning to use for the blending of end points and how you would identify which segment to use.

Comment: Thanks - some good pointers for some reading around for me to follow up on (and good answer linked too - it's useful background!). Finding good candidates is definitely the problem - that's where I'm stuck - and I'm wary of picking random things and iterating just because it will tend to blow up compression time. Might be a good place to start experimenting though.

Comment: In terms of bit encoding, it's a variable rate coder (block-based, like BC7, but with some choice on block sizes based on regional spatial complexity). I'm aiming to get down to around 2 bits per texel, but currently I'm just playing with algorithms for finding candidates without a hugely expensive iteration phase (or at least with some good heuristics to drive where to push the search). I've honestly not gotten as far as specific bit encodings yet.

Comment: *"in terms of bit encoding, it's a variable rate coder (block-based, like BC7, but with some choice on block sizes based on regional spatial complexity)."* So it's a software-only idea? Not really intended for HW?

Comment: Yes, pure software. Mostly it's just an excuse to play with researching some better generic block-based coding strategies to be honest ;)